# Rufus doesn't support HDAT2

Tags: hard-drive, bootable-media, rufus

I want to install HDAT2 and create a bootable pendrive using Rufus. However, I always receive a message saying: 'This ISO image is either not bootable, or uses a compression or boot method not supported by Rufus.' I've tried installing different versions of HDAT2 and formatting my pendrive in various formats such as FAT32, NTFS, and exFAT. Unfortunately, I'm still encountering the same error.

[image: Error message]

Comment: Please see this:   https://hdat2.com/files/Create_DOS_USB.pdf

Comment: Does HDAT2 support UEFI mode or is it a legacy environment that only supports Legacy Mode? [Edit] your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: John, could you quote "Rufus utility 
Do not use HDAT2 CD ISO/IMG files for Rufus, it cannot work with them. " from your linked source in a full answer? You found the solution, credits belong to you!

Comment: Elias, please read John's link. If John does not provide a full answer instead of a comment during the next days, you can answer your own question which complies with the rules of this site. Do not just link the article but do not copy the whole article either. Quote the key point instead as a kind of a summary! Try it out! Welcome to superuser.com